# kronecker product of matrix columns in R>

Tags: matrix, product

Given a matrix `X`  `n` by `p`, and a matrix `Z`  `n` by `nz`.   I want
to form an array `W`  `n` by `p` by `nz` , where `W[,j,k]= X[,j]*Z[,k]`

I'm currently doing this via

```
  W=array(NA,c(n,p,nz))
  for(j in 1:p){
        W[,j,]=matrix(X[,j],n,nz)*Z
  }
```

I want to avoid loops so that this will be faster for large `n`,`p`,`nz`.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve it yourself? If so, post those trails. This helps other to avoid those and focus on the real solution. BTW.. without trail/error code it becomes less likely people are willing to spend time solving the issue at hand with you. Check: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: Tom- yes I tried something! See my original post

Comment: I'm not a math expert but had your question for review to see if its a true question. I've checked based on general info you gave and I concluded it was valid. However, the reason why this question was put for review is two ways.. you're new to SO and the type of question really needs an answer from an expert that understand this type of complicated math equations. ... wolfram, python, perl perhaps? Language hint? See also my previously posted link for that. And please finish the tour for rep and understanding how SO works!